# ForEach and the $_ empty result

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-cli

My Azure CLI task is this (`...` replaces my Azure credentials):

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
    azureSubscription: ...
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
    inlineScript: |
      $containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string ...)
      $containers.ForEach({ echo $_."name" })
```

`$containers` is a set of containers, each of which has a `name` property; writing `$containers.ForEach({ echo $_ })` I obtain something like:

[image]

First of all, I don't understand why there's the `[` in the top left corner, since I'm printing only the objects inside the array, not the array itself. Second, I can't figure out why the cycle doesn't print the `name` property of the objects when I write `$containers.ForEach({ echo $_."name" })`: it prints nothing, the output is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, because you are getting json, not an object, you should do this:

```
$containers = $(...) | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5
$containers.foreach{ $_.name } # dont need echo, just a waste of characters
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. I ask you also this: is it correct to write  `$containers|where{$_."name" -like "random*"}` to make `$containers` hold only those objects whose `name` property starts with "random"? I make use of the `*` character.

Comment: why do you keep asking new questions in the comments? you can do that, but I tend to use regex and `.where`: `$containers.where{$_.name -match '^random'}`. also, you dont need to quote property name (unless it has got spaces or something like that)

Comment: To avoid to ask _n_ different questions. Thanks.

Comment: @RHShanks92 Different questions are good because they solve different issues and problems :)

Comment: well thats the point of this site, asking questions. and its easier to search for them, compared to questions in the comments. also you cant really give me points for answering in the comments (not that you chose to do that anyway)